# Why is my session expiring every time I close the browser?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, express-session

I set up the session maxAge of express like documented.

Here is my code:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    maxAge: 1000* 60 * 60 *24 * 365,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection})
}));
```

But every time I close the browser, I find myself logged out.

Also, note that I am using Passport local, facebook, and google authentications.

They all expire.

In the console, I can see that the connect.sid in the expires/maxAge section lists "Session" while other cookies have dates...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sessions are based on cookies.  If the session goes away when the browser closes, then it's probably because the session cookie goes away from the browser.  That would either be because of a passport setting that specified non-durable sessions or because the browser has some setting to not retain cookies when the browser is closed.  You can literally examine the browser to see if the original cookie is still there or not.

Comment: "In the console, I can see that the connect.sid in the expires/maxAge section lists "Session" while other cookies have dates..." - So it's not a browser setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to configure your express-session, and set `maxAge` on `session-cookie`

```
app.use(express.session({
    cookie : {
        maxAge: 1000* 60 * 60 *24 * 365
    },
    store : new MongoStore({mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection})
});
//.....
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: That  was it! Thank you!